# Dropout layer ignored - "Warning: had one or more problems upgrading V1LayerParameter"

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to add a dropout layer based on the Imagenet example (see code below). However, it seems to be ignored it's not printed as being part of the network when I train the model and I get the warning message below. I have the newest version of caffe installed. What should I do to include it properly?

**Dropout layer:**

```
layer {
  name: "drop4"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc4"
  top: "fc4"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
```

**Training log:**

```
I0407 21:05:06.809166  5962 caffe.cpp:117] Use CPU.
I0407 21:05:06.809468  5962 caffe.cpp:121] Starting Optimization
I0407 21:05:06.809532  5962 solver.cpp:32] Initializing solver from parameters:
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 500
base_lr: 0.01
display: 100
max_iter: 10000
lr_policy: "fixed"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 1000
snapshot_prefix: "hdf5_classification/data/train"
solver_mode: CPU
net: "hdf5_classification/cnn_train.prototxt"
solver_type: ADAGRAD
I0407 21:05:06.809566  5962 solver.cpp:70] Creating training net from net file: hdf5_classification/cnn_train.prototxt
E0407 21:05:06.809836  5962 upgrade_proto.cpp:618] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter: hdf5_classification/cnn_train.prototxt
E0407 21:05:06.809968  5962 upgrade_proto.cpp:636] Input NetParameter to be upgraded already specifies 'layer' fields; these will be ignored for the upgrade.
E0407 21:05:06.810035  5962 upgrade_proto.cpp:623] Warning: had one or more problems upgrading V1LayerParameter (see above); continuing anyway.
I0407 21:05:06.810108  5962 net.cpp:257] The NetState phase (0) differed from the phase (1) specified by a rule in layer data
I0407 21:05:06.810132  5962 net.cpp:257] The NetState phase (0) differed from the phase (1) specified by a rule in layer accuracy
I0407 21:05:06.810143  5962 net.cpp:257] The NetState phase (0) differed from the phase (1) specified by a rule in layer pred
I0407 21:05:06.810266  5962 net.cpp:42] Initializing net from parameters:
name: "CDR-CNN"
state {
  phase: TRAIN
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "hdf5_classification/data/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 3
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 2
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 11
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 120
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
    kernel_h: 7
    kernel_w: 1
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "fc4"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "fc4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 84
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc4"
  top: "fc4"
}
layer {
  name: "fc5"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc4"
  top: "fc5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc5"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
I0407 21:05:06.810355  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer data
I0407 21:05:06.811199  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer data
I0407 21:05:06.811228  5962 net.cpp:338] data -> data
I0407 21:05:06.811259  5962 net.cpp:338] data -> label
I0407 21:05:06.811285  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up data
I0407 21:05:06.811301  5962 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:80] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: hdf5_classification/data/train.txt
I0407 21:05:06.811357  5962 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:94] Number of HDF5 files: 1
I0407 21:05:06.853078  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 14 7 24 (23520)
I0407 21:05:06.853113  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 (10)
I0407 21:05:06.853132  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853159  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853175  5962 net.cpp:380] conv1 <- data
I0407 21:05:06.853199  5962 net.cpp:338] conv1 -> conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853221  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853638  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 16 7 22 (24640)
I0407 21:05:06.853665  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu1
I0407 21:05:06.853684  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer relu1
I0407 21:05:06.853698  5962 net.cpp:380] relu1 <- conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853713  5962 net.cpp:327] relu1 -> conv1 (in-place)
I0407 21:05:06.853727  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up relu1
I0407 21:05:06.853744  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 16 7 22 (24640)
I0407 21:05:06.853757  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool1
I0407 21:05:06.853772  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer pool1
I0407 21:05:06.853785  5962 net.cpp:380] pool1 <- conv1
I0407 21:05:06.853799  5962 net.cpp:338] pool1 -> pool1
I0407 21:05:06.853814  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up pool1
I0407 21:05:06.853837  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 16 7 11 (12320)
I0407 21:05:06.853849  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2
I0407 21:05:06.853867  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv2
I0407 21:05:06.853878  5962 net.cpp:380] conv2 <- pool1
I0407 21:05:06.853893  5962 net.cpp:338] conv2 -> conv2
I0407 21:05:06.853909  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up conv2
I0407 21:05:06.854030  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 20 7 1 (1400)
I0407 21:05:06.854048  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu2
I0407 21:05:06.854063  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer relu2
I0407 21:05:06.854074  5962 net.cpp:380] relu2 <- conv2
I0407 21:05:06.854087  5962 net.cpp:327] relu2 -> conv2 (in-place)
I0407 21:05:06.854100  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up relu2
I0407 21:05:06.854113  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 20 7 1 (1400)
I0407 21:05:06.854125  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854140  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854152  5962 net.cpp:380] conv3 <- conv2
I0407 21:05:06.854166  5962 net.cpp:338] conv3 -> conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854179  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854748  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 120 1 1 (1200)
I0407 21:05:06.854771  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3
I0407 21:05:06.854785  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer relu3
I0407 21:05:06.854797  5962 net.cpp:380] relu3 <- conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854811  5962 net.cpp:327] relu3 -> conv3 (in-place)
I0407 21:05:06.854825  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up relu3
I0407 21:05:06.854838  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 120 1 1 (1200)
I0407 21:05:06.854851  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer fc4
I0407 21:05:06.854871  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer fc4
I0407 21:05:06.854883  5962 net.cpp:380] fc4 <- conv3
I0407 21:05:06.854897  5962 net.cpp:338] fc4 -> fc4
I0407 21:05:06.854912  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up fc4
I0407 21:05:06.855232  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 84 (840)
I0407 21:05:06.855252  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4
I0407 21:05:06.855267  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer relu4
I0407 21:05:06.855278  5962 net.cpp:380] relu4 <- fc4
I0407 21:05:06.855406  5962 net.cpp:327] relu4 -> fc4 (in-place)
I0407 21:05:06.855432  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up relu4
I0407 21:05:06.855447  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 84 (840)
I0407 21:05:06.855458  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer fc5
I0407 21:05:06.855582  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer fc5
I0407 21:05:06.855614  5962 net.cpp:380] fc5 <- fc4
I0407 21:05:06.855631  5962 net.cpp:338] fc5 -> fc5
I0407 21:05:06.855648  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up fc5
I0407 21:05:06.855674  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: 10 2 (20)
I0407 21:05:06.855690  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer loss
I0407 21:05:06.855710  5962 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer loss
I0407 21:05:06.855721  5962 net.cpp:380] loss <- fc5
I0407 21:05:06.855734  5962 net.cpp:380] loss <- label
I0407 21:05:06.855751  5962 net.cpp:338] loss -> loss
I0407 21:05:06.855768  5962 net.cpp:113] Setting up loss
I0407 21:05:06.855785  5962 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer loss
I0407 21:05:06.855813  5962 net.cpp:120] Top shape: (1)
I0407 21:05:06.855825  5962 net.cpp:122]     with loss weight 1
I0407 21:05:06.855854  5962 net.cpp:167] loss needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855865  5962 net.cpp:167] fc5 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855877  5962 net.cpp:167] relu4 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855890  5962 net.cpp:167] fc4 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855901  5962 net.cpp:167] relu3 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855912  5962 net.cpp:167] conv3 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855924  5962 net.cpp:167] relu2 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855937  5962 net.cpp:167] conv2 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855947  5962 net.cpp:167] pool1 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855959  5962 net.cpp:167] relu1 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855970  5962 net.cpp:167] conv1 needs backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855983  5962 net.cpp:169] data does not need backward computation.
I0407 21:05:06.855994  5962 net.cpp:205] This network produces output loss
I0407 21:05:06.856011  5962 net.cpp:447] Collecting Learning Rate and Weight Decay.
I0407 21:05:06.856029  5962 net.cpp:217] Network initialization done.
I0407 21:05:06.856041  5962 net.cpp:218] Memory required for data: 368124
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and stumbled upon this question:

[What does 'Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated transformation parameters' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253520/what-does-attempting-to-upgrade-input-file-specified-using-deprecated-transform)

As far as I know, in caffe's attempt to upgrade your layer architecture,
caffe has already found some layers that are written in the new protobuf syntax. Thus, it skips upgrading your old syntax and therefore ignores the Dropout layer.
But I am not 100% sure about this, as it's just my assumption, when taking a short look into the caffe code.

For me the solution was to change it as follows:

```
layers {
  name: "drop4"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc4"
  top: "fc4"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
```

Hope it works =)

Comment: alternatively, you can upgrade your prototxt into a tmp file (using the upgrade utility) and then add the dropout layer in the new syntax. At any rate it is best to move on to the new format, rather than down-grading to the old one, might cause compatibility issues in the future...